# Unable to Connect to Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, axapta

I have a problem, when deploying report libraries through Axapta tool or directly from node in Dynamics Ax. I'm receiving the error:

> Unable to connect to http://xxxxx/reportserver/ReportService2005.asmx as specified in the config file for the report server at c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.3\Reporting Services\ReportServer\RSReportServer.config.

Can anybody say what is wrong?

Comment: Please describe you server setup. How many servers are involved?

Answer (score 1):

Are you running another website on port 80 on the same server?
Consider have your reports run on a different port (ie 8080 or 81).

Also, there is a post about a similar problem here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/emeadaxsupport/archive/2010/01/20/internet-explorer-proxy-settings-can-interfere-dynamics-ax-2009-report-deployment.aspx